# Flutter iOS: Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit

Tags: flutter

I am upgrading to latest Facebook SDK, following the guidelines and when I run pod update I get the following error about not being able to resolve host: **origincache.facebook.com**

```
Installing AppAuth (1.6.1)
Installing Bolts (1.9.1)
Installing FBAEMKit (15.1.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (15.1.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (15.1.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (15.1.0)
Installing FBSDKMarketingKit (4.38.0)

[!] Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/sg/zx75t0_s3v371cvvj91d56800000gn/T/d20230614-13839-n510cb/file.zip https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.12.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.6.3'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
```